# Keeping the smart contract data when switching networks

Tags: solidity

Hello guys so im making a project that is going to run 1 month on the rinkeby test network but after it will switch to mainnet. The problem is that I would like to keep the contract data from the rinkeby network.Ik that its probably not possible but is there a solution without hardcoding it to the website or smart contract code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not possible for a contract on network A to inspect a contract on network B.

For a little more insight, blockchains cannot access external information at all because it is vital that the state of the contract can be *reconstructed* by any *any* node at *any* point in the future ... a property that cannot be maintained when there are references to external APIs or other chains. Bulk loading of information can only be accomplished by someone, somewhere, signing a transaction. a.k.a. "oracle".

You can consider different "exotic" patterns to try to minimize the need to commit data to the chain while making bulky information available to users. This is a matter of optimization ... not a departure from the principle - someone has to sign something.

As a word of caution, I might add that rinkeby doesn't have the same security properties as mainnet. Kicking things off with data that is more easily manipulable is a questionable way to bootstrap your mainnet contract.

Hope it helps.